# flutter checkbox with api value

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, containers

I need the container in the code below to take a bool value.
the row is inside a data table and I need each column to have one check box or one tap selected. whatever works.

```
   Container(
                height: 50.0,
                child: Column(
                  children:  row.getCells()[5].where((t) => CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(t),
                    value: isSelected,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      isSelected;
                    },
                  ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StatefulWidget` like this

```
  bool isSelected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text('Selected Item'),
              value: isSelected,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected = val;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: done, thank u.other resources i used below:https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-datagrid#:~:text=Overview%20The%20Flutter%20DataGrid%20%28also%20known%20as%20Flutter,also%20been%20optimized%20to%20handle%20high-frequency%2C%20real-time%20updates.          ,,,,,,,,,          https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12615/how-to-load-data-from-mysql-to-flutter-datatable-sfdatagrid